# Convert Text file to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have text files that I convert into Excel by copy/pasting them into Excel then go to DATA -> Text to Columns.

1. Then I choose Delimited.
2. Then select Delimiters Tab and Semicolon.
3. In the last step I choose Text for all fields.

Now I want to automate this by making a program in C#.

I will do some editing on the data in the Excel file. That could make a new Excel file if a specific column which would have a specific name and so on. So from one text file I could end up with three or four Excel files.

What are the relative merits of:

read the text file into a string/list then check the data then write the data to different Excel files?

or

use a TextToColumn() method in C# then start the editing then write it to a new Excel file?

If there are any other, better ways to accomplish such thing then please suggest.

EDIT: I see a lot of 3rd party suggestions, but I would like to do it myself so I can learn.

Comment: You can use a library like [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com) to create an Excel file in C#.

Comment: Why do you have to cut and paste, or create a program? Excel can import text files fine by itself.

Comment: "What have you tried, where is the data coming from? " it comes from a text file

Comment: "Why do you have to cut and paste, or create a program? Excel can import text files fine by itself." There is a lot of editing in the excel file like based on different rules it need to be split into different excel files. I just want to automate this that's why I will do a c# program.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one of two methods.

**First method:**
Use this code to convert the text file to an **csv** file

```
using System.IO;
void ConvertToCsv(string sourcefile, string destfile)
{
    int i, j;
    StreamWriter csvfile;
    string[] lines, cells;
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcefile);
    csvfile = new StreamWriter(destfile);
    for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        cells = lines[i].Split(new Char[] { '\t', ';' });
        for (j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
            csvfile.Write(cells[j] + ",");
        csvfile.WriteLine();
    }
    csvfile.Close();
}
```

Then open this file and save it as **xlsx** file.

**Second method:**

Use this code to convert the text file directly to an **xlsx** file.

```
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

void ConvertToXlsx(string sourcefile, string destfile)
{
    int i, j;
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    string[] lines, cells;
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcefile);
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
    for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        cells = lines[i].Split(new Char[] { '\t', ';' });
        for (j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cells[j];
    }
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(destfile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();
}
```

Don't forget to add this reference.
Project > Add Reference > Assemblies > Extensions
Choose "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

You can also do the checks you want of the values and write them to separate files.

Answer (score 1):

[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is a very good start. It helps you create Excel files programmatically. Our company is using it for a very long time now and it has proven itself to work well.

*You might want to try the older version 3.1.3, if you encounter crashes/bugs. We had some issues with the current version, just as a tip.*

Otherwise, you can always export to CSV if you don't want any libraries for any reason. That should be no problem to implement.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) library can also be used to convert the TXT to Excel:

```
ExcelDocument doc = new ExcelDocument();

//Read TXT file
doc.easy_LoadTXTFile(pathToTXTFile, "\t", ";");

ExcelWorksheet sheet = (ExcelWorksheet)doc.easy_getSheetAt(0);
ExcelTable sheetData = sheet.easy_getExcelTable();

//Some editing on the data in the excel file
sheetData.easy_getCell(row, column).setValue("newValue");

//Convert to Excel
doc.easy_WriteXLSXFile(pathToXLSXFile);
```

You can also create multiple excel files, starting from the initial loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the delimiters are and I'm assuming that you also have the column names. You can use nuget packages such as CSVHelper to quickly read in the file as a list of Objects and then write it out as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with bytecode77. EPPlus is an excellent tool to do what you need.